# Error using namelist in gfortran

Tags: file, input, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to read certain values from a test file, but gfortran keeps giving me an end of file error and I am not sure why. Here is the Fortran code:

```
    program mesh 
    implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)

    namelist /input/ x

    open(5,file='input.in')
    read(5,input)
    print*, x
    end program mesh
```

Here is my input file:

```
 &input 
   x=5/
```

I have tried multiple input files with using `&end` instead of `/` and having everything on the same line (with spaces).

Comment: I've applied code fragment markdown on "&end", but I suspect you may mean "`&` at the end".  Could you please check?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there have been similar issues around here regarding line ends.  Are you sure that the file has line delimiters correct for your OS?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error with `gfortran 4.8.4` on Linux. Can you tell us your `gfortran` version and the operating system?

Comment: I am starting to think it  might be related to my OS. I even tried a different compiler (f77) and it still had the same issue. What do you mean by line delimiters for my OS?

Comment: portability issues led me to abandon all use of `namelist` a decade ago.

Answer (score 2):

It should works once you move the "/" to a new line. The EOL character did not have any effect with gfortran version 4.6.3

```
&input 
x=5
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already got the correct answer, the simplest way to determine the format is to write a program to *create* a namelist file and then look at it for correct syntax.

Here's your program modified to do that [and I've added a second namelist]:

```
    program mesh
    implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)

    namelist /input/ x,y
    namelist /input2/ a,c

    x = 4
    y = 7

    a = 37
    b = 23

    open(5,file='input.in')
    write(5,input)
    write(5,input2)
    end program mesh
```

The generated file is:

```
&INPUT
 X=  4.0000000000000000     ,
 Y=  7.0000000000000000     ,
 /
&INPUT2
 A=  37.000000000000000     ,
 C=  0.0000000000000000     ,
 /
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. I still don't know why simply using the right format won't work, but at least I got a working file now.

Comment: @JXS832 Your compiler may have a bug. I cut the file down to a single `&INPUT X=4.0000000000000000,Y=7.0000000000000000/` and that worked [I'm using 5.3.1]. Even `&INPUT X=4,Y=7/` worked.